# Lost Windows while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, system-installation, data-recovery

I needed a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I googled and followed the steps and got it done, but the GRUB was not visible, so I made a reinstall and selected the option of deleting the previous Ubuntu and reinstalling Ubuntu. This option deleted all my data :( and my genuine Windows, and now I just have Ubuntu. I didn't even create a recovery media. I just have a system recovery image on my external hard drive. I want my genuine Windows back, but I don't know how to recover it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of GParted (search for it in your Dash) and a link to the tutorial you've followed?

Comment: which brand is your lap?

Comment: Hey do you find some solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-grub
```

the above will do the trick mostly. If not working then do the manually thing by editing Grub menu

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

## This entry automatically added by the Debian installer for a non-linux OS

## on /dev/sdb1

title Windows 7
root (hd1,0)
savedefault
makeactive
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
chainloader +1

**edit /etc/fstab so windows partitions are accesible in linux:**

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config

sudo ntfs-config
```

**add mount points in /media for windows partitions**

hope this helps